# How to finish all fetch before executing next function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

Using ReactJS, I have two different API points that I am trying to get and restructure: `students` and `scores`. They are both an array of objects.

**My goal is** : first, get students and scores, and second, with students and scores saved in state, I will modify them and create a new state based on students and scores state. In short, I have 3 functions: `getStudents`, `getScores`, and `rearrangeStudentsAndScores`. `getStudents` and `getScores` need to finish before `rearrangeStudentsAndScores` can run.

**My problem is**: sometimes `rearrangeStudentsAndScores` will run before `getScores` would complete. That messed `rearrangeStudentsAndScores` up. But sometimes it would complete. Not sure why it works 50% of the time, but I need to make it work 100% of the time.

This is what I have to `fetch` `students and scores` in my `Client` file:

```
function getStudents(cb){
    return fetch(`api/students`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then(cb)
};

function getScores(cb){
    return fetch(`api/scores`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then(cb)
};
```

I then combined them together:

```
function getStudentsAndScores(cbStudent, cbScores, cbStudentsScores){
    getStudents(cbStudent).then(getScores(cbScores)).then(cbStudentsScores);
}
```

In my react app, I have the following:

```
getStudentsAndScores(){
    Client.getStudentsAndScores(
        (students) => {this.setState({students})},
        (scores) => {this.setState({scores})},
        this.rearrangeStudentsWithScores
    )
}

rearrangeStudentsWithScores(){
    console.log('hello rearrange!')
    console.log('students:')
    console.log(this.state.students);
    console.log('scores:');
    console.log(this.state.scores);        //this returns [] half of the time
    if (this.state.students.length > 0){
        const studentsScores = {};
        const students = this.state.students;
        const scores = this.state.scores;
        ...
    }
}
```

Somehow, by the time I get to `rearrangeStudentsWithScores`, `this.state.scores` will still be `[]`.

How can I ensure that `this.state.students` and `this.state.scores` are both loaded before I run `rearrangeStudentsWithScores`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your code mixes [continuation callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and Promises. You'll find it easier to reason about it you use one approach for async flow control. Let's use Promises, because `fetch` uses them.

```
// Refactor getStudents and getScores to return  Promise for their response bodies
function getStudents(){
  return fetch(`api/students`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((response) => response.json())
};

function getScores(){
  return fetch(`api/scores`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((response) => response.json())
};

// Request both students and scores in parallel and return a Promise for both values.
// `Promise.all` returns a new Promise that resolves when all of its arguments resolve.
function getStudentsAndScores(){
  return Promise.all([getStudents(), getScores()])
}

// When this Promise resolves, both values will be available.
getStudentsAndScores()
  .then(([students, scores]) => {
    // both have loaded!
    console.log(students, scores);
  })
```

As well as being simpler, this approach is more efficient because it makes both requests at the same time; your approach waited until the students were fetched before fetching the scores.

See [`Promise.all` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Works like a champ. I struggled with a similar problem for several hours before I found your answer. Thank you for posting a concise (and correct!) sample.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to wrap your functions in arrow functions. The functions are being invoked as the promise chain is being compiled and sent to the event loop. This is creating a race condition.

```
    function getStudentsAndScores(cbStudent, cbScores, cbStudentsScores){
  getStudents(cbStudent).then(() => getScores(cbScores)).then(cbStudentsScores);
}
```

I recommend this article for additional reading:
[We Have a Problem with Promises by Nolan Lawson](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

And here's a repo I made that has an example for each of the concepts talked about in the article.
[Pinky Swear](https://github.com/illuminatedspace/pinky-swear)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend restructuring slightly - instead of updating your state after each fetch call completes, wait for both to complete and then update the state all at once. you can then use the `setState` [callback method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to run the next method you would like to.

You can use a Promise library such as [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to wait for multiple fetch requests to finish before doing something else

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

getStudents = () => {
  return fetch(`api/students`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json());
};

getScores = () => {
  return fetch(`api/scores`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json());
};

Promise.join(getStudents(), getScores(), (students, scores) => {
    this.setState({
        students,
        scores
    }, this.rearrangeStudentsWithScores);
});
```

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` with native ES2015 Promises.

Comment: `Promise.join` is defined in bluebird, which I imported and mentioned above - we could certainly use `Promise.all` as well, and wrap the 2 function calls in an array!

Comment: My point is that you don't need any dependencies to solve this issue :-)