# Returning JSON object from fetch API with promise

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I'm using the fetch API to get some JSON data I want to work with:

```
function getMarkes() {
    return fetch(url, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Accept': 'application/json' } })
        .then(response => response.json())
}
```

This is the data that gets returned by the call:

```
["2",[{"id":"1","title":"title","lat":"52.011544629651524","long":"9.974744319915771"},{"id":"6","title":"title","lat":"51.3459148340574","long":"12.363418747546348"},{"id":"5","title":"title","lat":"52.48111410935233","long":"13.517611467320194"},{"id":"9","title":"title","lat":"51.6640392982322","long":"9.7315917652179"},{"id":"8","title":"title","lat":"52.516952093701605","long":"13.463058471679688"}]]
```

When outputting it here I only get a "2", not the whole JSON object.

```
getMarkes()
    .then(([markers]) => {
        console.log(markers);
    })
```

When outputting it in the getMarkes Promise itself I get the whole JSON object.

Comment: Why do you have the `[]` around markers?

Comment: I was orienting around this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980331/260308

Comment: Oh, that's breaking the array input out into multiple inputs.  You don't need that.  You only have one json input.  Remove the `[]`

Comment: `[markers]` is a destructing assignment. The first value in the array is assigned to `markers`. See the duplicate.

Comment: You're right. Man, I should make a break :) Thanks.